# Create a batch file to publish website ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, web, web-deployment

I have created a batch file, but it is not publishing.
Here is my script:-

```
set msbuildpath=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
"%msbuildpath%\msbuild" "MyWeb.sln" /t:ReBuild /p:Configuration=Release/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=D:\BlaBla\SourceCode\blabla\Properties\PublishProfiles\Pub_Test.pubxml
pause
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi after going through many articals, finally I got my solution.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild MyWeb.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=D:\BlaBla\SourceCode\blabla\Properties\PublishProfiles\Pub_Test.pubxml /p:Password=myPassWord /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```

This is wroking for me.

Comment: With this , only build is happening for me. Please help